# We are getting this message in android store,Webrtc version is outdated for xamarin.Android app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, webrtc-android

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/12577537

We are getting this message in android store. Fixing it is not mandatory for releasing but its a security risk.

Please help,how to update webrtc version.

Answer (score 0):

Google stopped providing Android library directly for webrtc, but the source is open and the link you shared has instructions on how to build the Android library from source.
It is a long process, but if webrtc is essential for your app, you have to spend some time to set this up.

If you need a temporary fix, I found that someone does this in their github repo often, and you can use the Android library there directly
https://github.com/dbrgn/webrtc-android

Note that, the author of this library itself recommends to build the library from the source directly.
https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/bO-d15ogjCs